# how can i read a txt file and format part of the txt into a table using python

Tags: python, create-table, read-text

i am trying to read a text file and extract a specific part from it to a CSV file ,

```
#**This is the part of the txt file:**#
- 172.16.1.202
- Hostaname: S01
#################################################################################
- VLAN-IP addressing Sheet
##########################
- VLAN + Description
--------------------
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Vl1                            up             up       
Vl5                            up             up       Legacy-RC-Admin
Vl20                           up             up       Legacy-RC-server
Vl30                           up             up       Legacy-RC-iSCSI
Vl40                           down           down     WAN Interconnect VLAN
Vl50                           up             up       
Vl60                           down           down     Tech FW ICS
Vl101                          up             up       RFR Data
Vl131                          down           down     Data WLAN
Vl134                          up             up       WLAN Management
Vl151                          down           down     Factory WLAN
Vl201                          up             up       RFR Management

- VLAN + IP address
--------------------
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Vlan5                  10.26.95.33     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan20                 10.26.93.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan30                 10.26.93.65     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan40                 10.63.121.251   YES NVRAM  down                  down    
Vlan50                 10.50.50.54     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan60                 10.26.95.22     YES NVRAM  down                  down    
Vlan101                10.26.92.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan131                10.26.81.1      YES NVRAM  down                  down    
Vlan134                10.26.82.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan151                10.26.83.1      YES NVRAM  down                  down    
Vlan201                10.26.80.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up

- Subnet Mask
-------------
Internet address is 10.210.130.10/30
  Internet address is 172.16.1.202/24
  Internet address is 151.151.151.151/32
  Internet address is 10.26.95.33/27
  Internet address is 10.26.93.1/26
  Internet address is 10.26.93.65/26
  Internet address is 10.63.121.251/28
  Internet address is 10.50.50.54/24
  Internet address is 10.26.95.22/29
  Internet address is 10.26.92.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.81.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.82.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.83.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.80.1/24
##################################################################################
- LAN Sheet
############
- Access or Trunk with VLANs
----------------------------
interface Port-channel2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface Port-channel1
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 channel-group 1 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
 channel-group 2 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,30,101,134,201,381
 channel-group 2 mode on
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
ip route 172.16.1.203 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/1

- Non user interface with Description
-------------------------------------
 Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Gi0/2                          up             up       Network link to eff-e-rfr-sw-as1
Gi0/3                          up             up       
Gi0/0                          up             up       
Gi0/1                          up             up       Network link to eff-e-rfr-sw-as1
Gi1/0                          up             up       Network link to eff-e-rfr-sw-as2
Gi1/1                          up             up       Network link to eff-e-rfr-sw-as2
Gi1/2                          up             up       
Gi1/3                          up             up       
Po2                            down           down     Network link to eff-e-rfr-sw-as2
Po1                            up             up       Network link to eff-e-rfr-sw-as1
Lo50                           up             up

- Remote port
---------------
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet0/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/1
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): mgmt0
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0
```

**The expected output is :**
[the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwVRc.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.read_csv()` with:

- `skiprows=8` to skip the first 8 rows
- `nrows=12` to read 12 rows
- `sep='\s{2,}'` to use multiple whitespaces as separator
- `names=['Interface','Status','Protocol','Description']` to set the column names manually, as the single space between the last two column names interferes with the multiple-space delimiter that is needed because the last row contains spaces in the cells.

The same for the next part, with adapted row values. Here we can `delim_whitespace=True` to use all whitespaces as delimiters, as there are no columns with whitespaces in the values. `pandas` can now also infer the column names automatically as there are no values with spaces in this table.

Finally, `join` both dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', skiprows=8, nrows=12, sep='\s{2,}', names=['Interface','Status','Protocol','Description'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', skiprows=23, nrows=12, delim_whitespace=True)
final_df = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_decription', rsuffix='_ipaddress')
```

Result:

|  | Interface_decription | Status_decription | Protocol_decription | Description | Interface_ipaddress | IP-Address | OK? | Method | Status_ipaddress | Protocol_ipaddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Vl1 | up | up |  | Vlan1 | unassigned | YES | unset | up | up |
| 1 | Vl5 | up | up | Legacy-RC-Admin | Vlan5 | 10.26.95.33 | YES | NVRAM | up | up |
| 2 | Vl20 | up | up | Legacy-RC-server | Vlan20 | 10.26.93.1 | YES | NVRAM | up | up |
| 3 | Vl30 | up | up | Legacy-RC-iSCSI | Vlan30 | 10.26.93.65 | YES | NVRAM | up | up |
| 4 | Vl40 | down | down | WAN Interconnect VLAN | Vlan40 | 10.63.121.251 | YES | NVRAM | down | down |
| 5 | Vl50 | up | up |  | Vlan50 | 10.50.50.54 | YES | NVRAM | up | up |
| 6 | Vl60 | down | down | Tech FW ICS | Vlan60 | 10.26.95.22 | YES | NVRAM | down | down |
| 7 | Vl101 | up | up | RFR Data | Vlan101 | 10.26.92.1 | YES | NVRAM | up | up |
| 8 | Vl131 | down | down | Data WLAN | Vlan131 | 10.26.81.1 | YES | NVRAM | down | down |
| 9 | Vl134 | up | up | WLAN Management | Vlan134 | 10.26.82.1 | YES | NVRAM | up | up |
| 10 | Vl151 | down | down | Factory WLAN | Vlan151 | 10.26.83.1 | YES | NVRAM | down | down |
| 11 | Vl201 | up | up | RFR Management | Vlan201 | 10.26.80.1 | YES | NVRAM | up | up |

You can save the dataframe to a new `csv` file: `final_df.to_csv('filename.csv')`

Comment: its a txt file not a csv file should i save it in a csv file ?

Comment: Not necessary, just use the txt file in `read_csv`.

Comment: ok las question , if i have other raw data in the txt file ,which i need for example to skip 3 row then i will need to add this txt to the same table but different columns and other will be added to the same column for ex this text is found after 3 rows of unnecessary data   : 
Internet address is 10.210.130.10/30
  Internet address is 172.16.1.202/24
  Internet address is 151.151.151.151/32
  Internet address is 10.26.95.33/27
  Internet address is 10.26.93.1/26
  Internet address is 10.26.93.65/26
  Internet address is 10.63.121.251/28
  Internet address is 10.50.50.54/24

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying. It is difficult to visualize without seeing what the file looks like. Could you update your question with what you want to know, or post a new question if this is a different issue?

Comment: i have edited the txt file in the main question , i want for example to add another column for [Interface I,P-Address ,Method ,Status)  aftet skiping three rows from the file and also will skip description column and ok column

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer. You can play with the row values for any other part that you would like to extract.

Comment: how can i do the same process but not with skipping rows as i want to apply the code with diffrent txt files?

Comment: You'll have to tweak the setting if other files are formatted differently. It all depends on how the specific files are formatted.

Comment: i mean the files will differ for example that the n0. of interfaces will be increased , so by using the row method the code will be shifted, is there a way to grap a specific elements by its name or another way not by counting rows?

Comment: If you know how the filenames correlate with the number of interfaces you could write a custom function that populates the `nrows` value dynamically. If you need help with that, please open a new question because it is a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link [Turning a text file into a tabular format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137878/turning-a-text-file-into-a-tabular-format) I think you are looking for the same answer thanks which are already explained there.

Comment: but i have a problem that the txt file contain some data i don't need it like the first 7 lines &
the needed part of the txt file looks like that with this spacing :
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Vl1                            up             up       
Vl5                            up             up       Legacy-RC-Admin
Vl20                           up             up       Legacy-RC-server
Vl30                           up             up       Legacy-RC-iSCSI
Vl40                           down           down     WAN Interconnect VLAN